# Delete partial duplicates in an array

Tags: arrays, duplicates, power-automate

Using Power Automate, I would like to remove partial duplicate items in an array. Below is an example. How can I end up with only 2 items (order numbers 123 and 456) in the array?

```html
[
  {
    "cr52a_ordernumber": "123",
    "cr52a_date": "12-15-22"
  },
  {
    "cr52a_ordernumber": "123",
    "cr52a_date": "12-14-22"
  },
  {
    "cr52a_ordernumber": "123",
    "cr52a_date": "12-16-22"
  },
  {
    "cr52a_ordernumber": "456",
    "cr52a_date": "12-17-22"
  },
  {
    "cr52a_ordernumber": "456",
    "cr52a_date": "12-18-22"
  }
]
```

Comment: So you want the one with the latest date? Also, can you please post your JSON as text and not as an image

Comment: Not necessarily. I know how to sort the data if I need to. I just want to delete all but the last or first item in the sub-array.

Comment: So if I’m hearing you correctly, you want the distinct set of order numbers? If you want the last and the first then just grab them. If your list contains more than two order numbers then your suggested approach won’t work. So is there a chance of having more than two order numbers? Your answer to that question will dictate my answer.

Comment: Yes. To compare it to Power Apps, I wish I could set a distinct formula on the Order Number column.

Comment: There could be more than two per order number, yes. That's why I can't just grab the first or last. I was trying to run an Apply to Each on the array and creating sub-arrays to remove all but the first or last item in those sub-arrays and append those sub-arrays to yet another array. But I don't know if there's an easier way.

Comment: There’s an easier way but it will cost, not expensive though. Will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

The `Advanced Data Operations` connector has an operation for exactly this purpose.  There is a small cost per month if you decide to sign up but you can get a trial and see what else it has on offer as to whether or not you find it useful.

This is what I tested with ...

[image: Flow]

Your array of data is contained within the first `Initialize Order Array` step.

This is the end result ...

[image: Result]

Comment: This looks like it would do the trick, but I can't justify $8+ a month for something this minute.

Comment: Yep, cost is always a factor so that’s fair enough.

Comment: FYI, this connector just came way down in cost.